# Macs2 peak calling?

Tags: chip-seq

I have paired end ChIP-seq data with 101 bp and 2 biological replicates for each one. I have done peak calling with macs2 but I have some questions about it.

I also faced with an warning:

> WARNING @ Thu, 07 Jun 2018 17:06:05: #2 Since the d (197) calculated from paired-peaks are smaller than 2*tag length, it may be influenced by unknown sequencing problem!
>   WARNING @ Thu, 07 Jun 2018 17:06:05: #2 You may need to consider one of the other alternative d(s): 197
>   WARNING @ Thu, 07 Jun 2018 17:06:05: #2 You can restart the process with --nomodel --extsize XXX with your choice or an arbitrary number. Nontheless, MACS will continute computing.

1. I have added `--nomodel --extsize 197 ; --nomodel --extsize 147` and `--nomodel --extsize 202` (separately to macs2 command) and got the results without any warning? Which one is more correct?
2. Are broad peaks extended of narrow peaks? If I apply intersect between them I should expect find 100% overlap between narrow peaks and broad ones?
3. Which kind of peak (narrow/broad) is proper for H3k27ac, H3k4me1, H3k4me3, H3k27me3 study?
4. If there is no control group for using as background, can I use default parameters?

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/319418/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your original command without `--nomodel --extsize ...` is probably the most accurate. This warning stems from a time when reads were much much shorter and likely never made that much sense to begin with.
2. Broad peak calling in MACS2 basically works by finding a bunch of nearish narrow peaks and merging them. If you have really broad signals then use something like `histoneHMM` instead.
3. H3K27ac, H3K4me1 and H3K4me3 are narrow. H3K27me3 is broad.
4. Yeah, but you'll need to spend a bit more time with the data to ensure that the peaks are reasonable (you'll have to tweak the parameters if not).

Comment: Adding to Devon Ryan's answer, see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olCjj.png) from [ENCODE](https://www.encodeproject.org/chip-seq/histone/).